# Compilation error involving functions being declared twice and the types being different

Tags: c, compiler-errors

When I try to compile my simple starter program, I get the following error:

```
In file included from processcommand.c:1:
processcommand.h:5: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token  
processcommand.c:3: error: conflicting types for 'getinput'  
processcommand.h:3: error: previous declaration of 'getinput' was here  
processcommand.c: In function 'getinput':  
processcommand.c:8: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast  
processcommand.c: At top level:  
processcommand.c:12: error: conflicting types for 'printoutput'  
processcommand.h:4: error: previous declaration of 'printoutput' was here
```

My code files are:
**main.c**

```
#include "main.h"

int main() {
    float version = 0.2;
    printf("Qwesomeness Command Interprepter version %f by Zeb McCorkle starting...\n", version);
    printf("%s", getcommand());
}
```

**main.h**

```
#include "includes.h"
int main();
```

**includes.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

**processcommand.c**

```
#include "processcommand.h"
getinput() {
    char *output;
    printf(" ");
    scanf("%s", output);
    return output;
}

printoutput(char *input) {
    printf("%s", input);
    return 0;
}

getcommand() {
    printoutput("Command:");
    return getinput();
}
```

**processcommand.h**

```
#include "includes.h"
char *getinput();
unsigned char printoutput(char *input);
char *getcommand();
```

I believe that those are all of my source files. I compiled with

```
gcc main.c processcommand.c
```

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Your function declaration does not match your function definition.

Comment: are you sure this is really all your code? The error in processcommand.h is of the kind that "shouldn't happen". There's nothing in the code you posted that could cause that. What is line 5 of processcommand.h ?

Comment: @mypal125: Why did you omit return types and parameter lists in your function definitions? Note, BTW, that parameter-less functions in C are declared with `(void)` parameters, not as simple `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the default return type is `int`, so `getinput()` means `int getinput()`

try changing:

```
#include "processcommand.h"
getinput() {
char *output;
printf(" ");
scanf("%s", output);
return output;
}
printoutput(char *input) {
printf("%s", input);
return 0;
}
getcommand() {
printoutput("Command:");
return getinput();
}
```

to

```
#include "processcommand.h"
char *getinput() {
char *output;
printf(" ");
scanf("%s", output);
return output;
}
unsigned char printoutput(char *input) {
printf("%s", input);
return 0;
}
char *getcommand() {
printoutput("Command:");
return getinput();
}
```

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks for the answer. This is the one that makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

In `processcommand.c`, it says

```
getinput()
```

what is an abbreviation of

```
int getinput()
```

which is a function with unspecified parameters and an `int` return value.

In `processcommand.h`, however, you have

```
char *getinput()
```

which is a function with unspecified parameters and a `char *` return value.

What you probably want on both places is

```
char *getinput(void)
```

which is a function with no parameters and a `char *` return value.

`printoutput` and `getcommand`  have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following errors starting with:

> error: conflicting types for ...

Are due to the fact that you are not implementing the functions as you declared them, for example you declare:

```
char *getinput();
```

but implement like so:

```
getinput() {
char *output;
printf(" ");
scanf("%s", output);
return output;
}
```

Which will assume a return value of `int`. If you modify your implementation like so:

```
char *getinput() {
...
```

it should fix that error. Unrelated to that error you need to allocate memory for `output` in `getinput`:

```
char *output = malloc(...); //
```

otherwise you are writing to an uninitialized pointer.